# Parse PHP Arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing

I've some PHP source code that are simple key-value arrays like these:

```
return array('var1' => 'var2' );
```

And

```
return array('sub' => array( 'var1' => 'var2' ) );
```

And I need to parse them into JavaScript objects, because I've a JavaScript implementation of a PHP library and I want to test the compatibility using the original test cases.

There are over a 100 tests, so manual conversion is not practical.

Is there an easy way to convert these into JavaScript objects without using PHP?

Comment: Why not use JSON? Why without PHP?

Comment: Json is fine but since the test framework runs in a node.js app PHP isn't a good option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To actually answer your question – how to parse PHP's associative arrays to JSON without using PHP – let's use some JavaScript code.

```
"array('sub' => array( 'var1' => 'var2' ) );".replace(/array\(/g, '{').replace(/\)/g, '}').replace(/=>/g, ':').replace(/;/g, '').replace(/'/g, '"');
```

This is assuming you just happen to sit on some source code and want to copy it into a [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) application, and that all the data looks exactly like this. If the data happens to be on multiple lines, if you even want to parse away the "return"/";" parts, if some of the data contains indexed arrays, or if any of the values contain the string I just naively parse away, you'll have to make this script a bit smarter.

And as others have said, if you're interacting with a PHP service, just use `json_encode()`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot simpler than I thought it would be.

Answer (score 2):

This should work!

```php
<?# somefile.php ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json = '<?= json_encode(array('sub' => array( 'var1' => 'var2' ))) ?>';
    var object = JSON.parse(json);
    console.log(object);
</script>
```

Output

```json
{
  sub: {
    var1: "var2"
  }
}
```

---

More commonly, you will see a language-agnostic API which simply provides JSON responses. You could easily test this using asynchronous requests to the API from JavaScript (in-browser, via [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js), etc.);

Comment: is there a need for `JSON.parse` ? what if you write `var object = <?php echo json_encode(array('sub' => array( 'var1' => 'var2' ))) ?>;` instead?

Comment: Object literals are not defined in JSON; they are defined in JavaScript's [object literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals). They are similar, but they are not the same.

Comment: I thought JSON was a subset of object literals syntax, therefore if something is valid JSON it would be a valid literal?

Comment: Yeah, almost, but [it's not](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset). Just parse the JSON as intended and you won't have any strange side effects.

Comment: you're right! also, in your link it shows a valid JSON string that isn't even a valid javascript string (after quoting it). not that I understand why it's like that..

Comment: also, with `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` in php I think unicode characters aren't an issue.

Comment: If I could use PHP that the way I would do it.

Comment: @mabs, what are you talking about "If I could use PHP"? The first five words of your question are "I've some PHP source code"

Comment: @naomik I think mabs is trying to convert code, from php to javascript in node.js. not use php to print to client side javascript

Comment: @naomik, look at the last sentence in my question :)

Comment: A clearfication:
I've a reimplementation of a PHP Library written in JavaScript. The original PHP library has a lot of unit tests that I'd like to use.
The JS implementation runs in Node.js and already have some JS specific test cases.

This is why I can't use PHP for this.

Comment: Why would any part of PHP be **re**implemented? /me is ashamed

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you need to use [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) like this:

```
return json_encode(array('sub' => array( 'var1' => 'var2' )));
```

The returned value: `{"sub":{"var1":"var2"}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_encode()` in PHP and `JSON.parse()` in JavaScript.