# Regular expression - remove square brackets from results

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string as follows:

```
var str = 'Array
(
    [shopUsername] => tod
    [password] => 12345678
    [shopID] => 19
)';
```

I'm trying to parse this in JavaScript using the following regular expression:

```
var matches = parsedXMLStr.match(/\[(.*)\]/g);
```

which returns each of the key values as `[ '[shopUserName]', '[password]', '[shopID]' ]`.

How do I change the regular expression to strip out the square brackets from the returned values, i.e. the array should be `['shopUserName', 'password','shopID']`.

Comment: get the group from index 1.

Comment: Use `exec` instead. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913667/javascript-regex-global-match-groups

Comment: Is this string being emitted from a PHP service that can be modified? (if so, you could try something like `json_encode`, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16118772/344143)

Comment: if the brackets are properly closed the you may consider this `[^\[\]]*(?=\])`, https://regex101.com/r/fU4hC6/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to grab the groups:

```
var str = 'Array(    [shopUsername] => tod\n    [password] => 12345678\n    [shopID] => 19)';
var match;
var results = [];
var regex = new RegExp(/\[(.*)\]/g);
while(match = regex.exec(str)) {
    results.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(results);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5d1rkLxw/)

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
str.replace(/[\[\]']+/g,'')
```